# Load Other sites Div using $('#div_content').load('page.html');

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add:

```
$('#div_content').load('page.html');
```

into an App so that grabs announcements from my school's site, so when they update the site, it updates the apps page, and im not sure if its because im stressed and keep missing it, but how would i have it load the div "page-content" from said "URL" using the above script, sorry if this sounds stupid!

Comment: Why don't you just use IFrame?

Comment: Unless the other site explicitly allows it, you can't make Ajax calls to an external site.

Comment: Its a word-press site that i Administrate how would i go about allowing it?

Comment: @newboyhun because i dont want the page to load, in an App that would be ugly, i just want the formatted text from a specific Div content

Comment: Use RSS, would be a good way if you can use PHP, or other preprocessor

Answer (score 0):

Simply put - you can't load HTML from other domains (like your school) unless they explicitly allow it by enabling [Cross Origin Request Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).  You can ask your school's IT administrator, but I don't think they'd be too keen on it, as CORS opens up a whole host of security issues.

Your best option is to use an [`<iframe>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe):

```
<iframe src="page.html" width="400" height="400"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like i might look for another way to get them, since i can't pull the div content...

Comment: @JzJad the 'other way' is iframes, like I suggested.

Comment: iFrame was a very basic option from the start but seeing as it loads the page, and its very ugly, i need a clean look, but thanks.